# different options for different groups in k6

Tags: javascript, k6

I have to rewrite `.jmx` file to k6. The migration tool did not work.
In `.jmx` file there was a test plan with two thread-groups. Each thread group has different number of threads and loop counts.

Originally I wanted to do it like this

```
export default function () {
    group('JMX file test plan', () => {
        group('first thread group', () => {});
        group('second thread group', () => {});
    });
```

I thought to use `options` with configured `vus` and `iterations`.

```
export let options = {
    stages: [
        { vus: first-group-threads, iterations: first-group-loops },
        { vus: second-group-threads, iterations: second-group-loops }
    ],
}
```

But as far as I understand it will execute all groups two times - with first stage parameters and second stage parameters.

Is there a way to execute each group with its own amount of `vus` and `iterations`? Or I have to create separate test files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stages` is not an equivalent to thread groups, and you can't use `iterations` in a stage.

We're currently very actively working on supporting multiple executors, which would be the thing to support your use case exactly. You can follow the effort in [PR #1007](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/pull/1007). Until it's merged in `master`, you can either build the branch yourself to use the new features (it's somewhat unstable and has a few known bugs), or use separate test files.

Comment: So basically I have to create separate files for each jmeter thread group?

Comment: Yes, for the next month or two at least.